# Alignment of elements to text/ numers (tikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, formatting

I experience some trouble with following tikzpicture. Due to the fact that this is a code sample belonging to a larger model, I am not able to extend the distance between the elements in horizontal (extending vertical would be fine). However, you can see that the numbers overlap the lines. Do you have any idea/ suggestions how my problem can be solved?

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning, shapes,arrows}
%opening
\title{TikZ-Problem}
\author{Jens}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto,>=latex,align=center,
latent/.style={circle,draw, thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=10mm},
manifest/.style={rectangle,draw, thick,inner sep=2pt,minimum size=10mm},
mean/.style={regular polygon,regular polygon sides=3,draw,thick,inner sep=0pt,minimum
    size=10mm},
paths/.style={->, very thick, >=stealth'},
variance/.style={<->, thick, >=stealth', bend left=270, looseness=2},
arrow/.style={-latex, shorten >=1ex, shorten <=1ex, bend angle=45}
]
\node [latent] (LV1) at (0,0) {Factor};
\node [manifest] (WR) [below =of LV1]  {Indic1};
\node [manifest] (SI) [left = 0.5cm of WR]  {Indic2};
\node [manifest] (IN) [right =0.5cm of WR]  {Indic2};
\node [latent] (EIN) [below =of IN]  {Error};
\node [latent] (ESI) [below =of SI]  {Error};
\node [latent] (EWR) [below =of WR]  {Error};

\draw [paths,above] (LV1) to node   {0.999}   (IN);
\draw [paths,above] (LV1) to node [pos=.75]   {0.999}   (SI);
\draw [paths] (LV1) to node   {0.999}   (WR);

\foreach \e in {IN, SI, WR}
\draw [paths] (E\e) to node   {1}   (\e);
\foreach \x/\xlab in {EIN/0.111, ESI/0.111, EWR/0.111}
\draw [variance] (\x.south west) to node [swap] {\xlab}  (\x.south east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can basically scope and change the node distance and then fiddle with the nodes

```
\node [latent] (LV1) at (0,0) {Factor};
\begin{scope}[node distance=1.5cm]
\node [manifest] (WR) [below =of LV1]  {Indic1};
\node [manifest] (SI) [left = of WR]  {Indic2};
\node [manifest] (IN) [right = of WR]  {Indic2};
\end{scope}
\node [latent] (EIN) [below =of IN]  {Error};
\node [latent] (ESI) [below =of SI]  {Error};
\node [latent] (EWR) [below =of WR]  {Error};

\draw [paths] (LV1) to node[midway,sloped,above]   {0.999}   (IN);
\draw [paths] (LV1) to node[midway,sloped,above]   {0.999}   (SI);
\draw [paths] (LV1) to node[midway,sloped,above]   {0.999}   (WR);
```

[image]